# extends Activity with Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using `Fragment` for Sliding Menu. Now, I want to extend `Activity` to get reference of layout.xml and many more. But we can't bind `Fragment` and `Activity` together.
 So what is the way to solve this ?
**Fragment Code :**

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

    public FindPeopleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.becomeexpert, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

If I am using extends `Fragment` then I can't use findViewbyId and many more things. So I am confused as I am using Fragment first time.
 Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the view inflated you can call rootView.findViewById(...)

Comment: Can you give me any tutorial for more information regarding different elements for Fragment.?

Comment: Is there a certain type of information you looking for? I looked at the android developer site for information on fragments when i first started with them: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html or http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html. maybe this video can help as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGXenxtDEGQ

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after:

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView;

private View myTextView;

public FindPeopleFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.becomeexpert, container,
            false);

    myTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);

    return rootView;
}

private void someFunction()
{
   View myButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
}
```

}

You can save a reference to the views that you need before onCreateView returns, or you can save a reference to the rootView and call findViewById on that later on if you need to.